# Find the length of list present inside the dict

Tags: python

`sf` is my dictionary that looks like:

```
    sf = {'DummyCustomer9': 
          array([list(['DummyCustomer9_subfolder1', 
                       'DummyCustomer9_subfolder2', 
                       'DummyCustomer9_subfolder3'])]
                ,dtype=object)
```

I used the below piece of code to get the length, but it has returned me length of `j` is `1`. Ideally it should count inside return me `3`. How can I get the count of elements ?

```
     for i,j in sf.items():
        print(len(j)),j)
```

output

```
1 [list(['DummyCustomer9_subfolder1', 'DummyCustomer9_subfolder2', 'DummyCustomer9_subfolder3'])]
```

Comment: it's 1 because it's 1 array. what's the purpose of nesting a list in an array here?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I count the elements here?

Comment: Maybe `len(j[0])`?

Comment: Why do you write `list([...])`? The `[...]` syntax already creates a list, you don't need to convert it.

Comment: It's like writing `int(1)` or `str("foo")` -- the functions are redundant.

Comment: len(j[0]) worked!
You are a savior. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your code as you do not need to have `list()` within the `array()` you can simply have a list set out with `[]`, so rather than:

```
sf = {'DummyCustomer9': 
          array([list(['DummyCustomer9_subfolder1', 
                       'DummyCustomer9_subfolder2', 
                       'DummyCustomer9_subfolder3'])]
                ,dtype=object)
```

you would have:

```
sf = {
    'DummyCustomer9': np.array(
        ['DummyCustomer9_subfolder1', 
         'DummyCustomer9_subfolder2', 
         'DummyCustomer9_subfolder3'], dtype='O')
```

Therefore it is a lot easier to get the length of the `list` within the `np.array`, by doing:

```
for k, v in sf.items():
    print(len(v), v)
```

For brevity the full code would be:

```
import numpy as np

sf = {
    'DummyCustomer9': np.array(
        ['DummyCustomer9_subfolder1',
         'DummyCustomer9_subfolder2',
         'DummyCustomer9_subfolder3'], dtype='O')
}

for k, v in sf.items():
    print(len(v), v)
```